# The react app is not working in the pod of AKS

Tags: docker, containers, azure-aks

The docker image works properly in local. But when I use it inside the AKS, the react page isn't showing up. I fetch the same image from container registry that I used inside the pod.

But it not works.

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder

# Declaring env
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Setting up the work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Installing dependencies
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copying all the files in our project
COPY . .

# Building our application
RUN npm run build

# Fetching the latest nginx image
FROM nginx

# Copying built assets from builder
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copying our nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Nginx.conf

```
server {
 listen 80;
 
 location / {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }
}
```

### Output file should show the react page, not this text.

[image]

### Pod content:

[image: pod data]

Comment: I haven't solved the problem. But I can say the Issue is related to  K8's policy. Try to Check Network Requests using a browser and K8's Network policy. Let me know the outcome.